# Showing multiple datasets using paste function?

Tags: r, loops, paste

I have a question on using the "paste" function in R.

Setting:

I have 1000 datasets with (5 X 100) dimension for each.

They are called X1, X2, ..., X999, X1000, respectively.
I would like to see just the first row of each dataset.
For example, X1[1,], X2[1,], ... , X999[1,], X1000[1,].

However I would like to use a loop to save time.
Here's my code that generates an error msg eventually.

```
plot(X1[1,], type="s", col = "deeppink1",
  xlab = "Steps")

for(t in 2:1000){
lines(paste("X", t, sep="")[1,], type="s", col = "deeppink1")
}
```

The error msg says

```
Error in paste("final", t, sep = "")[1, ] : 
incorrect number of dimensions
```

I was playing around with this code to fix the problem, but could not solve it. Please help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you want [`get`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html).

Comment: `head(object, 1)` will show the first row in object.

Comment: I would use one of the iterating functions over a loop. Just much cleaner. Look up `apply`, `replicate`, etc. I think the best way to work with your data would be  transform it into an `array` and and have 1 3d array vs 1000 2d data.frames. Then you can just make a call to whatever dimension you are interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`paste("X", t, sep="")` is a string, not a variable.

You'd have to write `get(paste("X", t, sep=""))` to use your approach, but you should really put all your datasets in a list and loop through them :

```
for(t in 2:1000){
lines(your_list[[t]][1,], type="s", col = "deeppink1")
}
```

Comment: I'd think the use of `get` far preferable to `eval(parse(...))`. Do you know when/how `eval` would be preferred between the two?

Comment: `eval(parse(text=...))` would be used when the string is not a variable name

Comment: Sure ... I keep thinking about sql-injection (inadvertent as it may be), and the overhead of parsing. I think your recommendation for putting all frames in a single `list` is where the OP needs to head ...

Comment: Thank you so much, Moody_Mudskipper! I sincerely appreciate it! : )

Answer (score 0):

Here is an array solution. Since all your data.frames are the same dimensions you can very easily do this with an array.

**Example data:**

```
Your_array<-array(1:500000,dim=c(100,5,1000)) #rows, columns , frames
```

To display the first row of each data.frame

```
Your_array[1,,]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, CCurtis! It also perfectly works : )